# Does SQL Server 2008 have an equivalent to Oracle's “table%rowtype” syntax or (Data Type)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, scripting

In Oracle PL/SQL scripts, you can declare a variables using the syntax tablename%rowtype for its type. This will make that variable have the same "type" as a row of that table

(i.e. a it will be a structure with the same field names and types).

This is a convenient way to transfer data between database tables and PL/SQL.

I am looking at doing the same thing (Data Type) in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Is there an equivalent feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No version of SQL Server has this. It would be useful (PostreSQL has the same and I like it).

In SQL Server, there are table types ([`CREATE TYPE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx)), temporary tables ([`CREATE TABLE #foo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)) and table variables ([`DECLARE @var TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)), but you can't mimic or inherit a table definition using `%TYPE` or [`CREATE TABLE .. INHERITS/OF`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html)

Comment: Thanks , But i think it's  very perfect data type in oracle (i mean "table%rowtype") , and i don't know why MS SQl have not it

Comment: @gbn: Can't the [`SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) be used to create a table of the same type as an existing table?

Comment: @ypercube: yes, but limited. You have no keys and can't be used in parameters like PG CREATE FUNCTION. It's nowhere as near as useful and I can't see how it replaces the %TYPE concept.